# How to pass Bash commands from Python to a running Docker Container

Tags: python, bash, docker

I am running a Docker where I enter bash mode, and can input some commands. While that Docker is running, is it possible to send these bash commands via a Python script?

This is a strange use case, but it seems necessary in this instance.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you define the use case?

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes is ok running commands inside the container, but for the general case, you should modify the `ENTRYPOINT` of the image for running the commands you want to.

Also, you should define your use case, maybe it's not as strange as you think.